# "Temporary failure in name resolution": Symfony 5.3 Connection to MariaDB with Doctrine and Docker

Tags: php, mysql, docker, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got my dev environment running in docker (nginx, php and mariadb) and try to create a database in symfony with doctrine. When I run `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` , I will get the following error:

```
[critical] Error thrown while running command "doctrine:database:create". Message: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution"
```

My configuration in `.env` looks like this:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://admin:symfony-admin@db/symfony_test?serverVersion=mariadb-10.1"
```

And this is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./code:/code
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    depends_on:
      - php

  php:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./code:/code 
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "33006:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'symfony-root-pwd'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'symfony_db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'symfony-admin'
```

I also use adminer to have access to the database and there the login works.

Does someone know why I can't create a database with doctrine?

Cheers,

Michael

### **Solution:**

I found the solution by myself. The command `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`  need to be run within the php docker container and not in the local terminal.
So at first `docker-compose exec php /bin/bash` and then `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`

Answer (score 2):

You can add

```yaml
links:
      - db
```

to `php` service config and change your `DATABASE_URL` to
`DATABASE_URL="mysql://admin:symfony-admin@db/symfony_db?serverVersion=mariadb-X.X.X"`

Service `db` will be exposed to `php` service, and in `php` container `db` will be host (link) to `db` service

Comment: Hi Maxim, I tried this out but unfortunately it doesn't work. I edited my post with your suggestions. Did I something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this problem is in the password. As the Connection String is a URL, that encodes the special characters thinking it is a parameter.

To make it clear, fixing this requires one of these 2 steps:

1. URL encoding of the password so that you get quoted (% encoded) characters, e.g. in .env.local or .env:

For example, by replacing character **#** by **%23** (its encoded version).

> -DATABASE_URL=mysql://user:special#password@localhost:3306/db?serverVersion=8.0
> +DATABASE_URL=mysql://user:special%23password@localhost:3306/db?serverVersion=8.0

2. Or Removing **resolve:** from doctrine.dbal.url in **config/packages/doctrine.yaml**:

> ```
> doctrine:
>     dbal:
>          url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
> ```

The first one works for me!

Answer reference: [Malformed parameter "url". Symfony 5 does not accept special characters. #35568](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/35568)